# Wildcards in uBlock websites not working

Tags: firefox, wildcards

I use uBlock0 on Firefox 40.0.2 and I the filter 
`*.stackexchange.com###hot-network-questions` in "My Filters" does not remove the element. When I replace `*.stackexchange`with `academia.stackexchange`, for example, it removes it as intended. Does uBlock not support wildcards or do I need a different syntax? `.*` instead of `*` does not help as well.

Comment: If I understood correctly, the example uses hash tags - I don't think it supports wildcards when used with  #

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your filter `*.stackexchange.com###hot-network-questions` is not an Adblock Plus-compatible filters -- see [Adblock Plus filters explained](https://adblockplus.org/filter-cheatsheet#elementhiding).

You do not need to use a wildcard: `stackexchange.com###hot-network-questions` will work on `stackexchange.com` and all subdomains of `stackexchange.com`.

Comment: But I use uBlock and not Adblock Plus, do they have the same filter rules? Edit: Just tested it and it works on all subsites, thanks!

Comment: @KonradHöffner Yes, they do.

Comment: `stackexchange.com###hot-network-questions` isn't working in Nov 2017.